# How to do the wiring of this capacitor

Tags: capacitor, motor, wiring

I have this (run) capacitor with 4 terminals for a sewing machine motor. I have fixed some minor issues but now I realize I don't know how the wiring was before.
I don't find an explanation for the scheme on the back of it anywhere so I post the image here
[image: Capacitor back]

Two terminals should connect the motor and the others two the pedal.

A front image, too, in case it helps:
[image: Capacitor front]

I have not found anything about this model/type anywhere

Answer (score 3):

This is not a capacitor but a mains input filter/Power line filter (which, as shown on the little schematic that is printed on top of it contains two capacitors and a common-mode choke) It's placed in series with the input - one side has the power line, other side has the device being powerd. If you are still not sure, I suggest googleing the topic.

Comment: I see. Red and yellow to input and black wires to coils. Thanks for the explanation and correction

Comment: I guess the motor can run without it, too. It blew up (old, I guess) and cannot find another one